# How to copy all files having the same name into another directory, with unique filenames, using bash?

Tags: bash

Say I have a directory structure like this:

```
├── Directory 1
│   ├── img.png
├── Directory 2
│   ├── imgx.png
├── Directory 3
│   ├── img.png
...
...
├── Directory n
│   ├── img.png
├── Images
```

I want to find and copy all the `img.png` files into the directory `Images`. Is there any way to:

1. Find all the `img.png` files (not all directories have this file)
2. Copy them into `Images` giving them unique filenames in the process (for example `2_img.png` if it is being copied from `Directory 2`).

Comment: What if there are more than one *img.png* at a given directory?

Comment: @Jetchisel There aren't

Comment: Is `x` a typo in `├── imgx.png` ?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin no, it is intentional. It is an example of a file that I do not want to be copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
for dir in 'Directory '*; do
  src=$dir/img.png
  dest=Images/${dir#* }_img.png
  if test -f "$src"; then
    echo cp "$src" "$dest"
  fi
done
```

Remove `echo` if the output looks good.